# Unix pipe in NX project.json

Tags: nrwl-nx, nrwl

Is it possible to pipe the output of an executor to a CLI command.

In `package.json` I would do this:

```
"dev": "node index.js | pino-pretty"
```

I cannot figure out how to apply this to the project.json

```
"dev": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/node:node",
      "options": {
        "buildTarget": "api:build"
      }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get it to work by creating a custom task:

```
    "pretty": {
      "command":"npx nx serve | pino-pretty"
    },
    "serve" ...
```

So now I use `npx nx pretty myproject` and that runs nx serve and pipes it to pino-pretty

Comment: I actually just switched to turbo repo - far less abstracted and not attempting to do everything.